# Data on metals and alloys properties (physical and chemical)

Tags: data-request, industry

Are there publicly available datasets of physical and chemical properties for (industrially produced) metals and alloys?

Answer (score 2):

MatWeb.com's page [Metal & Alloy Composition Search](http://www.matweb.com/search/CompositionSearch.aspx) has a searchable database, where you can search for metals and alloys by either (or both) of:

> Choose a Material Category

or

> Choose up to 3 Material Compositions

or search the entire [UNS (Unified Numbering System for Metals and Alloys)](http://www.matweb.com/search/SearchUNS.aspx), which

> is a systematic scheme in which each metal is designated by a letter followed by five numbers. It is a composition-based system of commercial materials and does not guarantee any performance specifications or exact composition with impurity limits. Other nomenclature systems have been incorporated into the UNS numbering system to minimize confusion.

The data sheets provide details about the physical, chemical, mechanical, electrical, thermal and optical properties, and the properties of the components of alloys are provided.  Further references are provided in each fact sheet.

Comment: Is this services has a open API or downloadable versions? I can't see.

Comment: There is a way to download pdf versions, if you register (free) here http://www.matweb.com/membership/benefits.aspx;some other options are for premium (cost) services